# html in helper with rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

I tried to build a helper with rails 5.1.

I need to have:

```
 <div class="card-sleep-body-price">
    <span>à partir de</span>
       <p>45.53€</
  </div>
```

I tried to build:

```
  def sleep_price(poi)
      if !poi.tariffs.blank?
        tag.div class: 'card-sleep-body-price' do
          <span>à partir de</span>
          <p>poi.poitable.tariffs.first.price '€'</p>
        end
      end
  end
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: It's nice to put myself -1... but it doesn't answer my question... thank you: D I'm Sorry, if I am a newbie  :(

Comment: what's the error? I mean, there must be a syntax error, you should post the errors when you ask for help. I guess you can use `content_tag` method for each node and you are done https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/content_tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way. Modified your code to use quotation marks and string interpolation to let Ruby know what's a literal and what is code.

```
def sleep_price(poi)
  "<span>à partir de</span><p>#{poi.poitable.tariffs.first.price}€</p>"
end
```

But, because it is considered bad form to have that long chain of dot notation in a helper or view, consider doing this logic in a model:

```
class Poi < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :poitable

  def price
    self.poitable.tariffs.first.price
  end

end
```

From a view, you might call this method as follows:

```
<%= sleep_price(match.sleep) %>
```

Alternatively, you could call `match.sleep` from a controller, perhaps setting it an instance variable available from the view.

A helper could look like:

```
def sleep_price(price)
  "<span>à partir de</span><p>#{price}€</p>"
end
```

Comment: If there 's bad  form ? How can I do ? What's a better way ?

Comment: It would be nice if `price` were passed in to the helper. The chain `poi.poitable.tariffs.first` that gets you to the price would ideally be in a model, or perhaps a controller. For example, if a `poi` always has only one price, you might want to implement a `poi.price` method in the `Poi` model that encapsulates that logic.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I'm not sure I understand. Can you explain it to me with an example?

Comment: Sure. I edited my answer to have an example. If this works out for you, please check my answer as correct.

Comment: Thank a lot John for yours explainations. Where do you test if price is no blank ? In the view ?

Comment: Good question. You could put that test in the view; that's not a bad way if you need the presence or absence of the helper call to be conditional on the test. However, the test is rather like "business logic", and if you look at it that way it should officially go in the model. One way to do this would be to create another function in the Poi model, perhaps named `has_a_price?`, and include the test in there. Then call that from the view. The principle at issue is called "separation of concerns", if you want to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Ben you can use Rails `content_tag` helpers for building html elements.

> ## view helper
>
> def generate_price(label:, price:, class: "element-class")
>
> > content_tag :div, class: class do
> >
> > > concat(content_tag(:span, label))
> > >
> > > concat(content_tag(:p, price))
> >
> > end
>
> end
>
> usage:
>
> `<%= generate_price(label: à partir de, price: 45.53€)%>`
>
> `<div class="element-class"><span>à partir de</span><p>45.53€</p></div>`

nested content_tag: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/nesting-content-tag-in-rails-3

content_tag: https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/content_tag

Hope this helps

Comment: The old syntax of content_tag and tag methods is still supported but might be deprecated and removed in future versions of Rails.

https://blog.bigbinary.com/2017/08/23/new-syntax-for-tag-helpers-in-rails-5-1.html

Comment: thanks for the info ben , yeah it might be depreciated soon yet there's no certainty about that, still `tag` helpers solved most problems for building `html` elements in rails.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a more elegant way to do this:

```rb
def sleep_price(poi)
  return if poi.tariffs.blank?

  tag.div class: "card-sleep-body-price" do
    concat(tag.span "à partir de")
    concat(tag.p "#{poi.poitable.tariffs.first.price} €")
  end
end
```